# Why am I getting extra white space when I remove the last comma?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I used several different posts on this site to figure out how to remove the last comma in a string. Apparently it's a classic question, but what I can't figure out is why it's adding an extra white space before the comma and not after the comma as one would expect?

As always I've played around with the code but I can't figure out where the extra white space comes from, please help me I'm going blind!

```
<?php $comma = ""; ?><?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?>
<?php echo $comma; ?><a href="<?php echo $tag['href']; ?>">
<?php echo $tag['tag']; ?></a><?php $comma = ","; ?>
```

Comment: Your code is not really that unreadable isit?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment nor does it seem relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank space is due to the line break in your HTML after the `<a>` element opens.

A better output soution would be:

```
<?php
$total = count( $tags);
$x = 0;
foreach ( $tags as $tag ){
    $x++;
    echo '<a href="' . $tag['href'] . '">' . $tag['tag'] . '</a>';
    if ( $x < $total ) echo ',';
}
?>
```

Comment: If you look at my other two attempts to convert this using php tags, you'll see I'm quite useless. I'm sure it works but without adding the extra tags, all I get are errors. For example, would I wrap the second statement like this `<?php $x = 0; ?>`

Comment: Sorry, the entire block should be wrapped in `<?php ?>`, updated above :)

Comment: I need to have each action enclosed inside tags otherwise it generates errors all over the place. Using your code as posted, it hates `{` for example. So, I have to enclose it all individually for it to work something like this, but it still sends errors because it likes to laugh at how stupid I am with php!?! argh! Here's how I managed to butcher it and still no luck: `<?php $total = count( $tags); $x = 0; ?><?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?><?php $x++; echo '<a href="' . $tag['href'] . '">' . $tag['tag'] . '</a>';
  if ( $x < $total ) echo ','; ?><?php } ?>`

Comment: That is a very strange thing... do you know what version of PHP you're running? And what type of server? I've never seen such strange PHP parsing! I ran your edited code in the comment above verbatim, supplied some data, and it worked for me. (PHP5 on Windows x64 - WAMPServer) Sounds like a problem not with your code, but with your server environment.

Comment: PHP5 on Windows x64 - XAMPP 1.7.7

Comment: I dumped xampp and installed wamp and guess what? problem goes away! Wow, thanks for that, much happier with wamp interface anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have a white space in your HTML code between the PHP tags... Why don't you rewrite it to something like this:

```
<?php $comma = '';
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo "$comma<a href='{$tag['href']}'>{$tag['tag']}</a>";
    $comma = ',';
} ?>
```

Comment: I don't know why I'm posting this because it's obvious it's not going to work, but I got this far and keep getting errors: `<?php $comma = ""; ?><?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?><?php echo "$comma<a href='<?php { ?>$tag['href']<?php } ?>'>{$tag['tag']<?php } ?></a>"; ?>
  <?php $comma = ","; ?><?php } ?>`

Comment: I don't understand... what happens when you do my code? What output do you get?

Comment: Also, you didn't convert my code well, here is the fixed version: `<?php $comma = ""; ?>
<?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?>
<?php echo "$comma<a href='{$tag['href']}'>{$tag['tag']}</a>"; ?>
<?php $comma = ","; ?><?php } ?>`  Again, don't forget to remove spaces between tags.

Comment: When I run the latest code you provided, I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`. I double checked the tags and they get input this way `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4` on the page they get displayed `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4,` when I add my original code I get `tag1 ,tag2 ,tag3 ,tag4`

Comment: That's weird, I get no errors for the code I gave you... But I see you've installed wamp and everything's fine now.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help and love the handle!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather write the whole thing as such:

```
<?php
$tag_strings = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
    $tag_strings[] = "<a href='" . $tag['href'] . "'>" . $tag['tag'] . "</a>";
    }
echo implode(',', $tag_strings);
```

Comment: I did this and get an error 'unexpected [' `<?php $tag_strings = []; ?><?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?><?php $tag_strings[] = "<a href='" . $tag['href'] . "'>" . $tag['tag'] . "</a>"; ?>
  <?php } ?><?php echo implode(',', $tag_strings); ?>`

Comment: You have an old version of PHP which doesn't have the `[]` shorthand for creating arrays. Do `$tag_strings = array();` instead.

Comment: xampp for windows php 5.3.8 - when I change the code as suggested I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'`

Comment: Sorry but that's not a valid argument...see my answer above it was the server and not me as you suggest.